# FactoryGirl::InvalidFactoryError: Validation failed: <Class> must exist (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, shoulda

I have these two models

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

These are my factories

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    id 1
    first_name 'John'
    last_name 'Doe'
    sequence(:email) { |n| "tester#{n}@example.com" }
    password 'secretpassword'
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :post do
    user_id 1
    title 'This is a title'
    body 'This is a body'
    published_at Time.now
  end
end
```

When I run the following tests I get the following error:

```
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  let(:user) { build(:user) }
  it { expect(user).to have_many(:posts) }
end

RSpec.describe Post, type: :model do
  let(:post) { build(:post) }
  it { expect(post).to belong_to(:user) }
end

# Error I get:
FactoryGirl::InvalidFactoryError:
  The following factories are invalid:

  * post - Validation failed: User must exist (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
```

How can I fix this?

This is also my db schema

```
  create_table "posts", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body",         limit: 65535
    t.datetime "published_at"
    t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end

create_table "users", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
  # Whatever devise generates
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution eventually. The key was missing was the `association :user`

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :post do
    title 'This is a title'
    body 'This is a body'
    published_at Time.now
    association :user
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
belongs_to :user, optional: true
```

> 4.1.2.11 :optional
>
> If you set the :optional option to true, then the presence of the
>   associated object won't be validated. By default, this option is set
>   to false.

You may refer to the [docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#optional) for more information.

Comment: I have already tried this, but I'm getting another error: `* post - Mysql2::Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`

Comment: @Lykos This occurs if child table contain some data with the foreign key that are not in parent table. In your case, `post.user_id` is foreign key of `user.id` and post table contain `user_id` that is not present in user table.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you're saying, but I generated this migration in order to associate posts - users `add_reference :posts, :user, foreign_key: true, after: :id` This is how I set the `post.user_id`

Comment: Wait, does this issue occurs because I use `build` instead of `create` in my tests??

Comment: @Lykos The `create()` method persists the instance of the model while the the `build()` method keeps it only on memory, so that could be the reason for the orphan record. Anyway, you should clean your test db.